# Orthonormal Basis in a complete Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that a complete Euclidean Space, not necessarily separable has a nonempty intersection.

Comment: What has non empty intersection ?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonality procedure to an arbitrary set of vectors and extend to a basis.

Comment: Hey Rick. I think this only works if it is seperable